# Tool to manage test lab computer bookings

Tags: resource-management

I work in a Test Competence Service, we have several testlabs, with various computers in different configurations. Some of these computers belong to a business unit and most of the time they are not used. But when these business units are to do their UAT they have priority.

At the moment, we do not have an overview of which computer is used by whom over which period of time. It would help us a lot to be able to book computers over a period of time and manage more efficiently the time these computer are used.

I'm looking for software to do so:

- booking of one or several computers in one go for a period of time (half a day to several weeks)
- computers can be grouped in "cluster" and have owners (business units)
- owner have precedence over other users
- user can book computer themselves, an admin could Or should validate (based on configuration)
- the solution provides suggestions for available computers during a given timeframe
- preferably open source, if not trial should be possible

Comment: You *have* to explain your abbreviations (UAT). We don't all live in your country.

Comment: What OS should it run on – or do you prefer web-based solutions? In the latter case: self-hosted, or SaaS?

Comment: UAT is User Acceptance Testing : basically users coming along from business production units. They comes in the Test Lab to validate if the project delivery is fit for production release.

Comment: Regarding OS, preferably web-based, on the server side either windows or Linux, preferably apache, jboss hosted.

Comment: “`preferably open source, if not trial should be possible`”. I think that you mean “preferably free”, in which case you should use the [tag:gratis] tag. There are probably more free/gratis solutions than open source.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement all this with the web-based open source software [Booked Scheduler](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/) as follows:

- Create one schedule.
- Create one resource "Test Run" and set it to unlimited availability. This lets users book it in parallel.
- Create one resource accessory type for each computer cluster.
- Set the availability of each accessory type to the number of computers in the corresponding cluster. (I assume that computers in one cluster are identical.)

Then, when creating a "Test Run" reservation, the user can add one or more accessories, requesting as many as they need from each available computer clusters.

The software knows which computers have already been booked in parallel and only shows those to the user that are still available for booking (in the whole selected time period). In this way, it "provides suggestions for available computers during a given timeframe".

Also, you would represent your "owners" as schedule admins in the software, which allows them to change booking as needed when they need the computers themselves.